# document.evaluate in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, xpath, xmlhttprequest, document.evaluate

I need help with this. I am new to using XPath in javascript and this one has stumped me.

My script retrieves the contents of a web page using xmlhttp and then wraps it up in a 'div':

```
            div=document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.replace(/<img[^>]*>/);
```

I need to access the body content of this wrapped division and I am using Xpath to do this:

```
bodyContent = document.evaluate("//*[@id='bodyContent']", div ,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);
bodyContent = bodyContent.snapshotItem(0);
```

While this works perfectly well in firefox and retrieves the required XpathObject it does not give the desired result for google chrome browser. Where instead of returning the bodyContent division of the 'div' element created (and passed as contextNode) it returns the bodyContent of the current document page.

I have checked and in chrome -- the correct xmlhttp.reponseText is received.

Any ideas regarding this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `document.evaluate(".//*[@id='bodyContent']", div ,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null)` give you the desired result in both browsers?

Comment: it is ok in firefox but not in chrome

Comment: And how about `document.evaluate("descendant::*[@id='bodyContent']", div ,null,XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null)`?

Comment: I apologize Martin, the first solution does work and also the second one and both in both browsers :) just like black magic :D.....Hocus Pocus!!! ....... Many thanks!